# Is it true that Google does not like copying pages and changing the keywords?

Tags: seo, search-engines, duplicate-content, negative-seo

I have created 3 web pages and optimized each for similar content (only change Keywords)  but different keywords & Meta Description in all 3 pages.

Is the okay to have similar content on these pages or the same content in some parts of the page?

I have created this page before 6 months and during that time it was rank in the top 5 but after google core algorithm update in May 2020. I was lost my page rank as well as site rank.

Is it true that my rank drops because of this similar or duplicate content?

Comment: Some unavoidable readings: [Avoid creating duplicate content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359) and [Duplicate Content](https://moz.com/learn/seo/duplicate-content).